# QML ImageProvider not displaying anything on Raspberry

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, qml, raspbian-buster

I have a Qt/QML project that works fine on Windows. Recently, I added an option to display some images in QML. Since I need to set those from C++, I used ImageProvider for that. It works fine on Windows, but when I compile the project on Raspberry Pi (Buster, Qt 5.12.4), it doesn't display anything.

I tried to insert some logging at some places and figured out the `requestImage` doesn't ever get called.

Here's how the provider looks like:

```
class ImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider {
    QImage image;
public:
    ImageProvider()
        : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image) {}

    void setImage(QImage img) {
        image = img;
    }

    QImage requestImage(const QString& id, QSize* /*size*/, const QSize& /*requestedSize*/) override {
        qInfo() << "Getting image from ImageProvider: " << id;
        return image;
    }
};
```

In QML, this is how it gets used:

```qml
Image {
    id: customImage
    source: ""
    anchors.fill : parent
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

    Timer {
        id: refreshTimer
        interval: 20
        running: false
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: parent.source = "image://images/imageContent"
    }

    function refresh() {
        source = "";
        /* If an image is already displayed, it won't refresh
           if I set source to empty string and then right away 
           to an image provider again, it won't notice. It has to
           tick in the meantime... This is a workaround, maybe there's
           a better solution*/
        refreshTimer.start();
    }
    Connections {
        target: rootItem
        function onImageRefresh() {
            customImage.refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

I do register the image provider, but that should be clear from the fact it works on Windows:

```
engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("images"), new ImageProvider());
```

As you can see, I'm using a kind of workaround to be able to refresh the image when it changes, but that is most likely not the problem because again, it works on Windows. The problem is that the function simply does not ever get called on Raspberry Pi.

`rootItem` is the context so that I can emit a signal from the C++ backend class. It's setup like this:

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("rootItem", (QObject*)this);
```

Where `this` is an instance of a class having this signal:

```
signals:
    void imageRefresh();
```

I emit the signal from C++ like this:

`emit view.imageRefresh();`

But obviously the signal is never received on the QML side.

Comment: Does the timer actually trigger?

Comment: The timer part definitely works fine on Windows. Will verify on Raspi...

Comment: @JarMan Looks like it doesn't thanks for the tip. Will try to dig in...

Comment: @JarMan Looks like the emited signal is not handled in QML for some reason. It's the connection you see above - `onImageRefresh`. Any idea on why this could be happening. Again, works on Windows...

Comment: I don't think I have enough information to answer that. What is `rootItem`? You'll need to provide a [mre]. Also, are you using the same version of Qt on both Windows and rPi?

Comment: Good questions both... `rootItem` should point to the C++ class doing the logic. Not an expert here, but I think that's the way it's supposed to be done: `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("rootItem", (QObject*)this);` I set the image from C++ - i.e. I need to be able to call the refresh function from C++.

As for the version... On Windows it's 5.15, on Raspi it's the one mentioned above. 5.12.4

Comment: @JarMan I have added the details. In the meantime I will try to come up with minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Aha, the syntax for Connections objects changed in 5.15 (which was really annoying). So the code you're using looks fine for 5.15, but for 5.12 instead of `function onImageRefresh()` it should look like `onImageRefresh:`. (Remove the word 'function' and the parentheses, and add a colon.

Comment: Massive thanks!!! That did the trick. If you add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it works on your Windows build but not your rPi is that you're using Qt 5.15 on Windows but 5.12 on your rPi. The code in your Connections block only works in 5.15. For some reason, Qt made a syntax change in 5.15 that broke backward compatibility. The older syntax should work on both, but I believe 5.15 will still nag you with warnings about it.

So to fix the code using the older 5.12 syntax, change your Connections object to look like this:

```
    Connections {
        target: rootItem
        onImageRefresh: {
            customImage.refresh();
        }
    }
```